# Controlar Errores MediaPlayer - Android

Tags: java, android-studio, mediaplayer

Tengo una aplicación en la cual reproduzco tres canciones que selecciono en un listView

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override   public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            for (int x=0;x<lv.getAdapter().getCount();x++) {
                lv.getChildAt(x).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            }
            lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
            cancionSeleccionada = i; // nos interesa saber qué canción ha seleccionado

                String texto = Integer.toString(cancionSeleccionada);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    });
```

Y reproduzco la canción seleccionada mediante un boton, el problema lo tengo en que si selecciono otra canción ya no me darle al boton stop o pause, y suenan las dos canciones, he intentado algo como esto que adjunto acontinuación para que al darle al play de nuevo deje de sonar lo que este sonando sin exito produciendome un error y cerrandose la aplicación. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Gracias.

```
  btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                                             mediaPlayer.stop();
                                         }else{
                                             mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                             int cancion = listaFicheros.get(cancionSeleccionada);
                                             mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, cancion);
                                             mediaPlayer.start();
                                         }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir toda la clase?

Comment: Es importante además de detener el MediaPlayer (stop()), liberar recursos (release() ) para que puedas cargar un nuevo audio al instanciar el MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final opte por la solución de cada vez que el usuario seleccione una canción en el listview se produzca el stop de la anterior y se empiece a reproducir la que acaba de seleccionar. Adjunto el código por si le puede servir a alguien de ayuda. Gracias.

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override   public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, 
int i, long l) {
            // deseleccionar la última canción si esta sonando
            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            //capturamos el click del usuario
            for (int x=0;x<lv.getAdapter().getCount();x++) {
                lv.getChildAt(x).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light));
            }
            lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
            cancionSeleccionada = i;
                //mostramos en un toast el título que se va a reproducir
                String texto = listaTitulos.get(cancionSeleccionada);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //hacemos que se reproduzca automáticamente la canción seleccionada sin interactuar con los botones
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            int cancion = listaFicheros.get(cancionSeleccionada);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, cancion);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e){

            }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que no continue con la reproducción es importante detener y liberar recursos para posteriormente cargar otro audio/video:

```
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
```

Es importante validar si el MediaPlayer fue inicializado, esto debe funcionar sin problema:

```
     btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }else{
                int cancion = listaFicheros.get(cancionSeleccionada);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, cancion);
                //Inicia reproducción.
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
          }
     });
```